# Web scraper with DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to scrape a web page for content, using `file_get_contents` to grab the HTML and then using a `DOMDocument` object. My problem is that I cannot get the appropriate information. I'm not sure if this is because I'm using `DOMDocument`'s methods wrong, or if the (X)HTML in my source is just poor.

In the source, there is an element with an id of 'cards', which has two child `div`s. I want the first child, which has many child `div`s, who in turn have an `anchor` child with `div` child. I want the `href` from the `anchor` and the nodeValue from it's child `div`.

The structure is like this:

```
<div id="cards">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="card-wrap">
            <a href="linkValue">
                <img src="..."/>
                <div>nameValue</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        ...
   </div>
   <div id="...">
   </div>
</div>
```

I've started out with `$cards = $dom->getElementById("cards")`. I get a DOMText Object, a DOMElement Object, a DOMText Object, a DOMElement Object, and a DOMText Object. I then use `$grid = $cards->childNodes->item(1)` to get the first DOMElement Object, which is presumably the `.grid` element. However, when I then iterate through the $grid with:

```
foreach($grid->childNodes as $item){
    if($item->nodeName == "div"){
        echo $item->nodeName,' | ',$item->nodeValue,'<br>';
    }
}
```

I end up with a page full of "div | nameValue" where nameValue is the embedded div's `nodeValue`, and I am unable to locate the `anchor`s to get their `href` value.

Am I doing something obviously wrong with my DOMDocument, or perhaps there is something more going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from your example code `if($item->nodeName == "div"){` is very going to preclude any `<a>` tag.  Additionally, I do not believe `childNodes` allows recursive iteration.

Therefore, to access the nodes in question, you *could* use:

```
$children = $dom->getElementById("cards")->childNodes
                ->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes;
```

Yet, as you can see this is very messy...  Introducing XPath:

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php
- http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I did the `if($item->nodeName == "div")` because otherwise it was outputting "text | nameValue" every other request, essentially duplicating my information. I should have been more clear on that. I didn't think this would be so tough as to need xpath, but I guess it's worth learning anyway...

Comment: The code I provided to you will work, should you not care to use xpath.  Although it would be easy to select with `card-wrap` too...  You have plenty of options here.  Use vardump to debug and you should be able to get what you want fairly quickly.  Kindly accept this answer if this all makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting yet, I wanted to see if someone else would chime in. I had tried the code you provided quickly and it did not give me the information It should have. I've been using vardump to figure out what each domdoc object contains...and the results I'm getting are not what I'd expect. I have a feeling it has to do with the source not being valid xhtml...

Answer (score 0):

The XPath way:

```
$src = <<<EOS
<div id="cards">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="card-wrap">
            <a href="linkValue">
                <img src="..."/>
                <div>nameValue</div>
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div id="whatever">
   </div>
</div>
EOS;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($src);

list ($anchor) = $xml->xpath('//div[@id="cards"]/div[1]/div[1]/a');
echo $anchor->div, ' => ', $anchor['href'], PHP_EOL;
```

"Get anchor of first child div of first child div of div with an id of 'cards'"

Output:

```
nameValue => linkValue
```