# web scraping - getting values of particular nodes inside an element

Tags: web-scraping, domdocument, getelementsbyname

I am having html like below:

```
<article class="">                 


 <p><strong>Jamshedpur:</strong> Three members of a family were beaten to death, allegedly by some villagers on charge of stealing a cattle in Udajo village of West Singhbhum district, police said on Saturday.</p><p>The incident took place on Thursday but the bodies, which were dumped in a jungle boring Naxal-hit Tonto area of the distirct, was yet to be recovered.</p><figure class="article_img">

            <img alt="" src="http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/2015/05/cowslaughter_reuters1.jpg">

            <div class="intro">File Picture
</div>
        </figure><!-- <div class="editor_pic clearfix">         
            <div class="fright eprbox ttu"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="opencomm()"><span>View all</span>1025 Comments</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="opencomm()" class="sprite_img ep_arrow"></a></div>
        </div> -->

        <div class="article_tag">
            <a href="/newstopics/cattle.html">#cattle</a> <a href="/newstopics/lynch.html">#lynch</a> <a href="/newstopics/theft.html">#theft</a> 
        </div><div style="height: auto; width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 0px; margin: auto; position: relative; overflow: hidden; background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" class="_adSenceImagePushContainer"><iframe width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" class="_adSenceImagePush" loadstatus="1" data-width="728" data-height="90" style="height:90px !important; min-height:90px !important; width:728px !important; overflow:hidden;bottom:0px;margin:0 auto 15px;position:relative; background: transparent; z-index: 2; -moz-transform: scale(1); -o-transform: scale(1); -webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1); max-width:initial !important;" hov-data-host="www.ibnlive.com" hov-data-section="news/*" hov-data-wom="web" hov-data-id="21" hov-data-default="true"></iframe></div><p>The victims were identified as Sukra Koda (30), his cousins Sanatan Laguri (32) and Surja Laguri (25). They were allegedly caught by the villagers and thrashed with lathis on charge of taking away a cattle, said the officer-in charge of the concerned police station, Sahdeo Toppo.</p><p>Toppo said the bodies have allegedly been dumped in the jungle but could not yet been recovered the area being a disturbed one.</p><p>A police team will be sent on Sunday to the spot to recover the bodies.</p><p>Meanwhile, an FIR has been registered against 13 villagers in this connection, he said adding that no one was arrested as yet. </p>             <!--tech poll -->




       <!--share and comment --> 
       <div class="editor_pic btm_share_box clearfix mtop30">

            <div class="social_icon_box fleft pnon bnon">
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li>

 <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://web.skype.com/share?url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html&amp;lang=en-US&amp;flow_id=e67bffb7-d317-4577-8528-e9cc76e80b38&amp;source=button', '_blank', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=305, height=665');"><img src="http://static.ibnlive.in.com/pix/ibnhome/ibn_revamp/newsletter/sky.png"></a>
 </li>
                             <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand&amp;url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html&amp;via=ibnlive&amp;related=cnnibnbreaking%2Cibnlivetech%2Cibnlivemovies','sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=620,height=320');"><span class="tech_sprite tweet_icons3"></span><div class="tlTweet"></div></a></li>
                             <li><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand&amp;u=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html','sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=620,height=280');"><span class="tech_sprite fb_icons3"></span><div class="tlFB"></div></a></li>                           
                              <li class="bnon pr_non"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="more_icon tech_sprite mtop5"></span> More+</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
<div class="social_icon_box share_exp_box">
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html&amp;t=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand"><span title="Facebook" class="tech_sprite fb_icons3"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand&amp;url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html"><span title="Twitter" class="tech_sprite tweet_icons3"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand"><span title="Pinterest" class="tech_sprite print_icons3"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html"><span title="Google+" class="tech_sprite g_icons3"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html"><span title="Linkedin" class="tech_sprite in_icons3"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html&amp;title=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand"><span title="Reddit" class="tech_sprite reddit_icons"></span></a></li>
                      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://www.ibnlive.com/news/india/3-lynched-on-charge-of-cattle-theft-in-jharkhand-1221561.html&amp;title=3 lynched on charge of cattle theft in Jharkhand"><span title="Stumble" class="tech_sprite stumbleupon_icons"></span></a></li>
                      <!-- <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="tech_sprite email_icons" title="Email"></span></a></li> -->
                      <!-- <li class="bnon"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="tech_sprite flipboard_icons" title="Flipboard"></span></a></li> -->
                    </ul>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sprite sclose_icon"></a>
                </div>
            <div class="fright eprbox ttu"><a onclick="clickpage('opencomments');" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>View all</span><div data-disqus-identifier="article_1221561" class="disqus-comment-count">0 Comments</div></a> <a onclick="clickpage('opencomments');" href="javascript:void(0)" class="sprite_img article_carrow"></a></div>    


        </div>
        <!--share and comment -->

       </article>
```

I want to fetch p tags inside article tag. I am using:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    if($page)
    {
        $doc->loadHTML($page);
    }


$paragraph = $doc->getElementsByTagName('article');

        $parag=array();

        foreach($paragraph as $para) 
        {

                if($para->nodeValue!="")
                {
                    $parag[]=$para->nodeValue;
                }

        }
```

But above code returns me whole content inside article tag whereas i want only p tags inside article.

I have tried using properties like nodeName and **childNodes** but it didn't help.
I have referred following links for understanding as I am naive to web scraping but could not find solution [tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/) and [childnodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461344/web-scraper-with-domdocument)

Please give me some exemplary solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: got solution:  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $news_paras = $xpath->query("//article//p");
  
  $parag = array();
  foreach ($news_paras as $news_para)
  {
    
   $parag[]=$news_para->nodeValue;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution above requirement can be met using xpath

```
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 
$news_paras = $xpath->query("//article//p"); 
$parag = array(); 
foreach ($news_paras as $news_para) 
{ $parag[]=$news_para->nodeValue; }
```